# Unable to print actual colors using sns.color_palette() (Matplotlib 3.5.2)

Tags: python, matplotlib, colors, jupyter-notebook, seaborn

I recently upgraded to Matplotlib 3.5.2. I used to be able to print the colors of a palette using, for example:

```
sns.color_palette("hls", 8)
```

As described in the [documentation](https://seaborn.pydata.org/tutorial/color_palettes.html), the above line should print the 8 specified colors.

Instead, I am getting the color codes:

```
 [(0.86, 0.3712, 0.33999999999999997),
 (0.86, 0.7612000000000001, 0.33999999999999997),
 (0.5688000000000001, 0.86, 0.33999999999999997),
 (0.33999999999999997, 0.86, 0.5012000000000001),
 (0.33999999999999997, 0.8287999999999999, 0.86),
 (0.33999999999999997, 0.43879999999999986, 0.86),
 (0.6311999999999998, 0.33999999999999997, 0.86),
 (0.86, 0.33999999999999997, 0.6987999999999996)]
```

I am using Matplotlib 3.5.2, Jupyter Notebook 6.0.3, Python 3.8.3. How can I get the colors to be printed? Many thanks and apologies in advance if I overlooked something obvious.

Comment: When I include as_cmap, I get a `color_palette() got an unexpected keyword argument 'as_cmap'`. This is why it's confusing to me (and never happened before I upgraded). What is this caused by? How do I print the colors, not codes?

Comment: `pip install seaborn --upgrade` fixed the issue. Thanks for your help anyway

Comment: What exactly is your question?  Note that `sns.palplot` would plot a colorbar with the chosen colors.  If you don't have any specific question, you might consider closing the post.